# Bower runs as Bundler on zsh/oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, bower, zsh-completion, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I run `bower install` or any `bower` command, it ends up running as `bundle install` or something else from `bundler`. I'm running a zsh shell with oh-my-zsh. It works as expected in a bash shell.

Example output:

```
% bower install
bundle install requires at least 0 argument: "bundle install".
```

Running `whence -p bower` yields `/usr/local/bin/bower`, which is symlinked to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower`.

Running `/usr/local/bin/bower install` works just fine. I'm thinking there is a place where bundle or bower has been aliased wrong, or oh-my-zsh's autocomplete isn't working properly, but I can't imagine where that would be. I could add `alias bower='/usr/local/bin/bower'` to my `.zshrc` but I'd like to solve this properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you report a bug? I reported one: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2486 but you should do it yourself next time.

Comment: @m_gol I didn't, as I eventually just uninstalled bower and bundler and reinstalled them and it started working somehow. Thanks for submitting that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally fixed this by uninstalling and reinstalling bower and bundler. However, it seems (as I thought) that ZSH was somehow overriding one with the other. @m_gol has been kind enough to submit a fix in oh-my-zsh to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.  Removed the bower plugin from my .zshrc file and everything started working again.

Comment: Did you report a bug?

Comment: just saw this on [bower github page](https://github.com/bower/bower): On prezto or oh-my-zsh, do not forget to alias bower='noglob bower'

Comment: I had to run `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` too, and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `whence -vs bower` to find zsh's interpretation of `bower`. `-v` will add the type if it's not a command, `-s` will also show a symlink-free path in case the pathname contains symlinks.

`whence -p bower` does a path search even if it is an alias or function and will only return found paths but nothing else. So this will not help you to find if it is an alias.